# Woocommerce query var 'order-received' causes a 404 error when used on page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, url-rewriting, woocommerce-subscriptions, custom-error-pages

if i try to add query parameter (order-received) in order-received page in woocommerce. it gives me 404 error.url is like http://localhost/order-received/?js:order=269017&key=wc_order_09fU1jATKarrE&order-received=269017

order-received page is custom page in wp. which is used as thankyou page after place order. i need to set order-received parameter value to order id. ineed to solve error.
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: order-received in /wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-subscriptions/vendor/woocommerce/subscriptions-core/includes/gateways/paypal/class-wcs-paypal.php on line 51

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a new query param then you have to go to the plugin file you mentioned class-wcs-paypal.php and there must be all params are calling, if there is new one then you have to add check for that param.

Also its just a Notice, if you go to wp-config.php file and turn the WP Debug to false then it will not show.

// Enable WP_DEBUG mode false
`define( 'WP_DEBUG', false );`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I need to fix that issue. I know it is Notice. In woocommerce default order received page that variable is set properly. but in my case it is my custom order received page. so i need to set that global variable value. but when i set it page goes to 404. if i set another variable name it will work but order-received is not working i need solution for that.